# How can I integrate a semantic reasoner into Sesame?

Tags: triplestore, sesame, reasoning

I'm working on the API for [TripleStore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) in [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org).  It has a reasoner which works with RDFs.

As I also work with [OWL](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim). So I want to add another [semantic reasoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner) such as [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/) or ITM ...

It appears that the SAIL API supports [customisable reasoning](http://owlim.ontotext.com/display/OWLIMv41/OWLIM-SE+Fact+Sheet) and it is [extend-able to other RDF-based languages](http://owlim.ontotext.com/display/OWLIMv41/Primer+Background+Knowledge#PrimerBackgroundKnowledge-TheSAILAPI).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How to do what, exactly? You've already found OWLIM, which is an OWL reasoner that is integrated with Sesame. There is no interface available between Sesame and Pellet, AFAIK, but if your goal is to "work with OWL", OWLIM should fit your need.

Comment: But where is the proper answer? This pages leaves one guessing.

Comment: @RomanSusi there is no proper answer because it isn't a proper question. As I said above: it's unclear what, exactly, the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Yes, no I see your point. It is not that an answer is not possible, but it is that it is not useful, because the question is vague. When reading back ago, I had applied my own interpretation, and the question was clear to me. Now that I know more, the question seems fuzzy. This is common problem on SO.